# Не воспроизводятся голосовые сообщения из бота на AIOGRAM с телефона

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

При отправке голосовых сообщений ботом с помощью метода SendVoice библиотеки aiogram, голосовое сообщение имеет следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осциллограмма выглядит так, будто в голосовом совсем нет звука, а указанная длительность - 0 секунд. На самом же деле голосовое сообщение там есть и длится оно 1 минуту и 51 секунду. При воспроизведении на компьютере оно получает следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот на телефоне (IPhone 11) оно вообще отказывается воспроизводится, вид сообщения при этом такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При воспроизведении не происходит ровным счетом ничего. Звук не идет, а сообщение повисает вот в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать возможным воспроизведение голосового сообщения на телефоне, а так же - как и можно ли исправить отображение голосового сообщения (чтобы корректно отображалась осциллограмма и длительность)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте файлы с расширением .ogg для того чтобы отображать длительность и акселерометр